# DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ....) not supported by Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, dense-rank

I have the following in my SQL:

```
SELECT   
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY i.invoicenumber) AS Reference
```

This runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio but is not supported by Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

I get the following SQL syntax error:

> The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported

Is there something else that I can use that will do the same job and will work in Visual Studio 2008?

Many thanks

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2008 **R2** - only VS 2008 - changed. There is a SQL Server **2008 R2** version (or Windows Server 2008 R2) - but not VS 2008 R2 ....

Comment: Visual Studio itself doesn't execute this SQL - it will pass it on to a SQL Server instance that handles it. So the question is: what **version** of SQL Server is your Visual Studio connected to? `DENSE_RANK` was introduced in SQL Server **2005** but it would *not* be present in a SQL Server **2000** version .....

Comment: Thank you - will go back to my IT dept and check the SQL server version

Comment: Sorry, Tried to amend my question but it wouldn't work.  I am running Visual Studio 2008 on SQL Server 2008 R2.  The query works if I run it in query pane on SQL Server Management Studio but I get the error message if I paste the same query into the query pane in query designer in Visual Studio.  I am quite happy to use a different query if necessary but don't know what to use that will do the same job.

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running it? I get the same error message from visual studio, but it still returns what I'm looking for.

(this isn't really an answer, but I don't have enough rep to post a comment!)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  In the end I pulled the data off of the query pane of the SQL Server Management Studio as it runs fine there.  I just couldn't save it as an .rdl file in Visual Studion and therefore could not load it to the front end of our Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  It just means that no-one else can run it at the moment.

Comment: Bit late, but something else is stopping you saving it as an rdl file. As the other commentators have said it's not visual studio that finally parses the sql, so you should be able to ignore the warning and carry on... unless something else is stopping you.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has no idea what the SQL means that you execute. It just sends it to the server. You are connected to a server that does not support this syntax.